# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':expo:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-studio, gradle

I am getting the following error trying to do `npx expo prebuild` & `npx expo run:android`:

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':expo:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not determine the dependencies of null.
   > Cannot query the value of this provider because it has no value available.
```

Why is it null?